# Black screen on boot and have to manually change the brightness

Tags: graphics, configuration

Issue:- Black Screen after boot-up

Ubuntu Version:- 12.04, 64 bit

Graphic Drivers Installation method:- Manually purged the old drivers and installed the new drivers provided by amd.

Tried methods:- added nomodeset option to /etc/default/grub and updated the grub using   sudo update-grub and restarted the system.

Effects:- Got the "System running into low graphics mode" error with mouse not working.

Workaround:- re-edited the /etc/default/grub file to remove the nomodeset option and updated the grub again.

My graphic card info is as follows:-
[image]

I want to get rid of the blank screen and i also don't want to loose my graphic card properties.

---

I just get the black screen and never see the prompt until I press the brightness keys.  Sir, the driver that I installed has the following properties:-

*-rwx--x--x 1 root  root  106660241 Jul 22 02:11 amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run*

I haven't removed the xorg.conf file; here is the screen shot of the file:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your question the same as this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/79983/screen-brightness-resets-to-minimum-after-every-reboot

Comment: yes sir, we can say that, but i am not sure about the reason. I have added the screen shot of the brightness values in my original question.