# Brightness and actual backlight mismatch after reboot

Tags: brightness, backlight

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot) or [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79983/screen-brightness-resets-to-minimum-after-every-reboot)!

**The problem in detail**

The brightness hotkeys works well in increasing or decreasing the brightness, but if the brightness is less than 100%, after a reboot the brightness level and actual backlight will mismatch; where I mean the actual backlight is not at its maximum while the brightness level shows 100%. **To avoid** such problem I should set the brightness level at 100% every time before shutdown.

**Efforts**

I’ve tried all suggested answers for brightness problems, including `acpi_backlight` in grub and `echo` values in *rc.local*, but no change. Recently I found that pressing brightness hotkeys while brightness settings window is open sometimes make the brightness slider disappear!

I’ve had this problem after 11.04, I mean in either 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10, and saw in various netbooks and laptops. I guessed it should be related to **unknown** graphics driver; because I had a known driver in 11.04 and no problem, but an unknown one in all computers with this problem:

[image: Unknown graphics]

So I just tried 13.04 via USB and faced the same problem although the graphics was **known**:

[image: Known graphics]

**A possible cause**

In the folder `/sys/class/backlight` there are two links (to folders):

1. **acpi_video0** which contains brightness files with the maximum **15**;
2. **intel_backlight** which contains brightness files with the maximum **125**. I wonder that in this folder `brightness` is 125 (at maximum) but `actual_brightness` is 70, even if the backlight is at its actual maximum.

Does anyone know about this or any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is updating grub such this:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Then find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash"` and add **"acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"** like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Save and exit the file, and run:

`sudo update-grub`

Now the brightness level stays equal to the actual backlight level after reboot, and brightness hotkeys remain working. All other hotkeys which were working before grub changed are working now, but the hotkey for enabling/disabling touchpad.