# Brightness 0% on Lenovo G500s on startup / boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, startup, brightness, lenovo

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo G500s Laptop. The screen is scrambled/shows weird artefacts during boot but that doesn't really bother me. What does is this:

The screen's brightness is always 0% on boot, which means that it is pitch black.

I've already searched this site and found two suggestions:

- `echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` in `/etc/rc.local`
- `/usr/bin/xbacklight -set 50` in `/etc/rc.local`

Both work fine (affect the screen's brightness) when I execute them from the Terminal, but when I put either of them in `/etc/rc.local` the display will still be pitch black on the login screen after a reboot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: G500s user! An ad hoc fix is to add `sleep 2` before `echo ...` in `/etc/rc.local`. This should work for you. A more consistent solution is (should be) this one of mine: http://askubuntu.com/a/375780/111720